# WSO2 products: zones of responsibilities

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Please, help me to undertand a zones of responsibilities all WSO2 products.
Now I'm a little bit confused for next questions:

1. If WSO2 Integration contains application server(which supports restfull ws), what for does WSO have also MS4J framework?
2. Am I right, that if I need to write business webservice(soap) I need to write it and deploy to WSO2 appserver? Or I can do this using WSO2 Integration(and how to do this in this case?)?

And the 3rd question not about above.
3. Let's assume I have some WSDL. I need to publish it and make linear mapping of it's methods to some rest API. Could anybody help with an example how to do this?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

1. MS4J is a new framework that is very much still in development. They are Java based microservice integrations so not really related to the enterprise integrator
2. The enterprise integrator contains the WSO2 application server see: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/About+this+Release

(3.) API's do not publish a wsdl. See [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+APIs+via+WSO2+ESB+Tooling) and [examples](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Creating+APIs) on how to create an API. You have to decide yourself how you can best implement the wsdl operations in an API.

Comment: 1. I know that this is a different products.. I just don't understand why they separated..
2. thanks)
3. By your links decribed REST API, the question was about soap.. probably do you know about it smth?

Comment: 1. MS4J is small and a currently limited framework of 9 megabytes, Enterprise intergrator is a powerful and large suite.
3. A I see, interpreted your question wrong. You can publish a wsdl like so:
- add wsdl to your registry (if there are xsd dependencies add them also) 
- add to the bottom of your proxy (below 'target') <publishWSDL key="local:[path to wsdl]"></publishWSDL>

then you can use for instance a <switch source="$trp:SOAPAction"> and a <send> with http endpoint to transform the soaprequests in the proper REST calls.